# Removing escaped unicode sequence in a text file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file with lots of unicode escaped sequence (of emojis by the way), for instance
`blablabla \uD83D\uDC4D\uD83C blablabla \uDFFC\uD83D\uDC4F\uD83C\uDFFD`
I'd like to remove it all, and get
`blablabla blablabla`

Is there Any regex expression which would clean these considering that i use Notepad++?

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is a community where you need to show your efforts before having answers. Follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) to start working on a solution. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest: `\\u[0-9A-F]{4}\s?`.

`\\u` escapes the slash and matches it and the `u` literal. `[0-9A-F]{4}` matches exactly 4 of these characters. Perhaps you should update it to also match length 2 characters depending on the actual text: `\\u([0-9A-F]{4}|[0-9A-F]{2})\s?`

The `\s?` matches zero or more whitespace so you don't end up with multiple consecutive whitespace characters.

Comment: `[0-9A-f]` matches digits, uppercase letters from `A` to `Z`, lowercase letters from `a` to `f` and some characters that take place between `Z` and `a` , for example `[`,`]`, `^`... Have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: it works like a charm! Thanks a lot! ^^

Comment: Moreover it matches much more than emoji!

Comment: You're entirely correct. I made a typo, I intended it to be an uppercase F